# Npm run build on my react app project doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

When i start my react project all seems good, but when i try to build this, it doesn't work, i have this error :

```
node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\darkx\Bureau\mlvojobs\mlvojobs\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\util'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2490:7)
    at toRealPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:394:13)
    at tryFile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:390:10)
    at tryExtensions (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:402:22)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:558:20)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\darkx\Bureau\mlvojobs\mlvojobs\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy\copy.js:7:22) {
  errno: -4094,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\darkx\\Bureau\\mlvojobs\\mlvojobs\\node_modules\\fs-extra\\lib\\util'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mlvojobs@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mlvojobs@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\darkx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-18T22_53_48_493Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\darkx\Bureau\mlvojobs\mlvojobs> npm install fs-extra
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\darkx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-18T22_54_15_541Z-debug.log
```

And when i try to install something with npm it says :

```
npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js sometimes works weird. I encountered this error, my option is switch to another Node.js version.

I recommend using [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) (seem like you're using Windows)

You can install latest Node.js version `lts`

```
nvm install lts
```

Or specific version, for example:

```
nvm install 16.16.0
```

Then delete your project `node_modules` and run:

```
npm install
```

Finally, build your project again. Let me know if it work!

Comment: Nice! I really appreciate if you accept my answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution  :

1. Go to  : `C:\Users(your username)\AppData\Roaming`
2. Delete the npm folder and if there is one npm cache folder.
3. Run `npm cache clean —force`

it should work